# Update a record based on condition in ios

Tags: ios, core-data

I am wondering how to update a row in CoreData? Every time I am updating a row, a new row gets added.

```
Project *saveProj = [self getProjectByFilterCriteria:predicate];

if (saveProj) {//based on predicate a single project object fetched.
    Project
    *obj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Project"
                                         inManagedObjectContext:[[AppManager sharedInstance] uiManagedObjectContext]];
     obj =saveProj;//then saving stuffs goes here down `
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are calling

> insertNewObjectForEntityForName

If you don´t want to insert a new item, then dont call that method. Just modify the object you want and then save it

```
if (saveProj) {
    saveProj.blabla = blabla
}
```

Comment: As per your saying i removed the insertNewObjectForEntityForName..but still its adding a new row.

Answer (score 0):

Use predicate to do update operations in core data
link: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001798-SW1